# How to specify the port serving CherryPy app in the DNS entry?

Tags: dns, cherrypy

I receive a "Port 80 not free" message when I try to serve my CherryPy app on port 80.  Most examples I see show folks using other ports.  If I use another port how do I specify the port serving my CherryPy app in the DNS entry?

We're using Easy DNS and from what I can tell there is no way to specify the port in the DNS entry.  Is this standard or a restriction with our provider?

Want to achieve something like this:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  -  www.domain.com:9595
```

Thanks in Advance!

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish the TCP port number for your web site in DNS, you can create an [SRV record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record), but there is no point in doing that since there are probably exactly zero web browsers in existence that actually query SRV records to find out which port to connect to.

So since SRV doesn't work, the short answer is to your question is, you can't. If your web server runs on a different port than 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS) then it is only possible to access it by specifying the port number directly in the URL, like **http://www.domain.com:9595/**.

If you really prefer to have your web site appear to be on port 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS) and there is already another web server listening on that port, then you can see if you can configure the other web server to proxy requests to your web server. For example, if the other web server runs Apache, then:

```
<Location /foo>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:9595/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9595/
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - we're up now.  You're Awesome!